# Bootstrap datetime picker use UTC but don' display the offset

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

So I added this script that displays datetime in bootstrap datetime picker in UTC format

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-D HH:mm:ss Z',
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now every time the date is displayed like

```
2017-02-16 08:44:00 +01:00
```

How can I use UTC date and time but not display the offset `+01:00` ?

Comment: throw away the Z in your format string...

Answer (score 0):

You can remove 'Z'.

```
$(function () {
        $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-D HH:mm:ss',
        });
    });
```

Comment: But then the time in my app will be saved in local time and not UTC. I want to display local for user and then save as UTC.

Comment: Oh why do you want this? And then you will save data different with user input, right?

Comment: So it's more user friendly. The offset doesn't need to be there because it's not important for the user, but I need to have UTC datetime saved in DB

Comment: Ok I got it. I think you can hide it using CSS, my friend :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion. You can create a global variable. Hope to help :)

```
var picker = $('#datetimepicker'l).data('datetimepicker');
var utcDate = picker.getDate();
```